# Apache Camel Loop does not stop on exception

Tags: loops, apache-camel

I have camel loop configured within the main route of camelContext.xml file that would invoke request processing route 3 times.  I have also configured onException xml handler (set handled to true).
However, when there is an exception on the first iteration the execution control goes to onException block but loop doesn't stop processing instead the other 2 iterations (2nd and 3rd) do happen too.

I would like to have loop stopped as soon as exception occurs.

Can anyone please help

Thanks in advance
Ramesh

Comment: Post your route please, or a smaller example route to illustrate the issue

Comment: What version of Camel do you use?

Comment: Using 2.14.0 version

Answer (score 1):

Ah its a bug in Apache Camel. I have logged a ticket and have a fix for this.

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-8945

Comment: Thanks for quick turn around Claus

May I know where I can get the fixed code from?  Also, if we can have some kind of chicken switch to enable breaking out of loop when exception occurs or continue looping even after the error occurs to provide max flexibility?

Comment: You can mark the exchange to stop. See source code for StopProcessor