# Apache Camel 2.13.0 quit splitter

Tags: apache-camel

I have a route with splitter. I need to stop the splitting-job each time it occurs something. Naturally onCompletion can help me but:

Regarding post "[Apache Camel Loop does not stop on exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31312281/apache-camel-loop-does-not-stop-on-exception)", it is a bug that if we use

```
.onCompletion().onFailureOnly()
    .process(new MyStopRouteProcessor("routeName"))
.end()
```

the splitter does not stop splitting. 
I have to use 2.13.0 and have not any choice. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Please include more of your code and try to describe a little more clearly what behavior you want.

Comment: My problem is exactly similar to the link I have mentioned here. 
I will quit a loop, before the loop is completed, in an older version of camel. it's clear I think :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the option `stopOnException=true` on the splitter as documented here: http://camel.apache.org/splitter

Comment: Thank you Claus. Why I missed this property, do not know :)