# OnCompletion.onFailureOnly not working when routing fails

Tags: java, apache, apache-camel, jms

I am trying to construct a route wherein if the final producer fails to post an exchange onto the destination queue, I should be able to update entries in my database for the the object contained in that particular exchange. The problem is that even when the delivery of the exchange fails, the onCompletion().onFailureOnly() part of the following route is note executed.

```
from(direct:start)
    .onCompletion().onFailureOnly()
    .process(new MyProcessor())
    .end()
    .to(jms:queue:myQueue1)
```

For example I tried to post to a IBM MQ queue that was already full. As expected, the message could not be put onto the queue but the onCompletion().onFailureOnly() part was not executed.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on your camel version. If you have possibilities to update the version, do it right away and it will work fine.
Otherwise use .stopOnException() instead.
Similar post here: [Apache Camel 2.13.0 quit splitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36156667/apache-camel-2-13-0-quit-splitter/36159707#36159707)